# Shopify App Proxy returning a 404 response

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I've used Shopify-CLI to generate an app and I've configured the app proxy as:

```
Prefix: tools
Subpath: sb
Proxy: https://xxx.ngrok.io/sb
```

In the theme.liquid page, I'm trying to access this as:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
            var response = xhttp.responseText;
            console.log("Sb ok"+ response);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/tools/sb/sessions", true);

    xhttp.send();
```

I'm able to hit https://xxx.ngrok.io/sb/sessions on my browser and get a valid response.

But the AJAX request constantly giving me a 404 on my test store. I've been able to configure an app proxy successfully using a different test app, and the only difference is this is a public app while the previous one was a custom app. I initially had a conflicting config i.e. /a/sb for both apps, but I've tried changing it to /a, /apps, /tools, with and without the subpath with no luck. I've even deleted the previous app to avoid any unexpected conflicts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try the same using the absolute URL?

Comment: As in, using the store name as part of the /tools/sb/sessions request? I could see that the GET request uses the right path from network logs.

Comment: According to Shopify documentation https://prnt.sc/1ra574y, it should works, but in your case /sb is the same as a subpath. I am not sure if it creates an issue or something else but you need to try a different subpath like Shopify example?

Comment: Will give it a try. Previously, I used the same subpath on my proxy and the Shopify config and it worked fine. So not sure what's special about a public app that causes the glitch. I also tested calling https://xxx.ngrok.io/... directly and that works fine too.

Comment: No luck with that change either. Looks like Shopify isn't using this config at all.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. Because I used the same prefix and subpath as the previous app (accidentally) when I first configured the app proxy, Shopify automatically suffixed a -1 to the proxy definition and the only way to change that was to go to the store and change the config. Changing the proxy URL in the partners/app setup flow didn't help.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Not sure why you got a down-vote!

Comment: Thanks @micwallace. People can be weird at times, and I'm glad to know the fix worked for you. Cheers :)